# Execution of PDO Prepared Statement with SQLSRV causing PHP to crash at Startup

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

(I'm French, sorry in advance for my english)
I had to work with SQLSRV. I used ODBC PDO to connect to the SQLSRV Database.
Here's my code:

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server='.$db_host.';Port='.$db_port.';Database='.$db_name, $db_user, $db_pass);
$req = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM account WHERE username = ?");
$req->execute([$username]);
```

When I execute it, PHP is crashing at startup (Firefox says "The connection was reset"):

```
[12-Dec-2016 07:09:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:  in Unknown on line 0
```

But if I do:

```
<?php
$req = $pdo->query("SELECT id FROM account WHERE username = '$username'");
```

or:

```
<?php
$req = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM account WHERE username = '$username'");
$req->execute();
```

It works.

I searched all over the web but no one seems to have the same problem. I'm working with WAMP, PHP5.5 and SQLServer 2016.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: I'm not sure if `execute` handles this internal (I bind the parameters always before), but parameters are 1-indexed and arrays are 0-indexed, so you could try `[1 => $username]` and see if it works. The error message is quite strange though. Do you run php-fpm?

Comment: Hi ! I already tried [':username' => $username], [1 => $username], bindParam() and bindValue(), always the same problem ! I don't run php-fpm, I'm using Apache (not sure if I've understood the question). Just tried with the CLI version of PHP and it crash too.